In teaching introductory databases to graduates and undergraduates how would you differentiate in exams/assignments?
If given the opportunity of teaching a course in databases for two different groups of students grad/undergrad, mostly from CS/Data Science majors, what are the approaches in order to differentiate in the exams/assignments for the two different groups of students?

I feel like this is backwards - exams and assignments are based on the course materials and goals, no? Are these kids going to be coming to the same lectures and have the same reading material? If so, then they would have the same assignments and exams.
